# Different results between two values handled by Sprintf function in PHP

Tags: php, printf

I'm learning Sprintf function in PHP. And I used two values for this function but I got different results as below:

```
echo sprintf('%.2f',15.455);
```

result is: 15.46

```
echo sprintf('%.2f',16.455);
```

result is: 16.45

I'm confused by the results, could you please help me out?